# Integration by parts in proof of special case of Ehrenfest's theorem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, physics

Our physics professor proved a special case of [Ehrenfest's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem), or to be more precise:
$$m\langle x\rangle = \langle p\rangle,$$
where we have used the definition:
$$\langle x\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi^* (x,t)\, x\,\psi(x,t)\, dx,$$
and $\psi$ is a normalized wave function.

In the proof at some point he writes the following:
$$\begin{align}\begin{aligned} \imath \frac { \hbar } { 2 m } \int _ { \mathbb { R } } d x\, x\, \Psi ( x , t ) ^ { * } &\frac { \partial ^ { 2 } } { \partial x ^ { 2 } } \Psi ( x , t )  = \imath \frac { \hbar } { 2 m } \left[ x \Psi ( x , t ) ^ { * } \frac { \partial } { \partial x } \Psi ( x , t ) \right] _ { x = - \infty } ^ { x = \infty } \\ & - \imath \frac { \hbar } { 2 m } \int _ { \mathbb { R } } d x \left( \Psi ( x , t ) ^ { * } \frac { \partial } { \partial x } \Psi ( x , t ) + x \frac { \partial } { \partial x } \Psi ( x , t ) ^ { * } \frac { \partial } { \partial x } \Psi ( x , t ) \right). \end{aligned}\end{align}$$
I really don't understand how the integration by parts works here and would be really happy if someone could explain this.

Comment: You integrate $\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}\psi(x,t)$ and differentiate $x\psi (x,t)^*$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: What do you not understand about integrating by parts here?  Let $u=x\Psi^{*}(x,t)$ and $v=\Psi_x(x,t)$.  Also use the fact that the wave function is of Compact Support.